# Set return value for class?

Tags: c++, class, parameter-passing, return-value, getter-setter

So I've been searching around to find some help but resulted in nothing. 
Is there a way to pass a class as a variable and have it reference a member of that class?

e.g. instead of

```
myclass foo; 
foo.Bar = 0.0f;
Func(foo.Bar);  //Func takes in a float.
```

if I wanted `Func` to know about `Bar` without me directly using an access operator inside or outside of the function. Almost like an automatic setter.

I want to be able to just do this..

```
myclass foo; 
foo.Bar = 0;
Func(foo);  //Func takes in a float.
```

Is there a way I can make `Func` pull `Bar` from `foo` like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Either provide an overload of `Func` that takes a `const myclass&`, or a [conversion function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) for xforming a `myclass` instance to its float member. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an implicit conversion function to your class:

```
struct myclass
{
    float Bar;

    operator float() const { return Bar; }
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Then you can use an object of type `myclass` whenever a `float` is required:

```
myclass x;
extern void f(float);
f(x);  // OK
```

Implicit conversions are usually a bad idea and this design doesn't seem very useful and will potentially pollute your codebase in ways you will eventually regret, but without context this is will Do What You Asked For.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Func(myclass &mc)
{
    float x = mc.foo;
   // do floaty stuff with x

}
```

then you can do

```
myclass foo; 
foo.Bar = 0;
Func(foo);
```

although maybe this is not what u were looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to define cast operator for you class;

Either globaly if flat_mbr is public:

```
operator float(const MyClass& ref)
{
    return ref.float_mbr;
}
```

Or as class member operator as Kerrek answered.